# Передача данных из nodejs в php

Tags: node.js

Как выгодней в плане экономии ресурсов сервера организовать передачу данных из nodejs в php скрипт?

На сервере используется apache+php и nodejs.
на nodejs крутится демон для работы с пользователями в реальном времени,
а основная логика на php.

я в nodejs новичок, в демоне подключены:

```
const md5 = require('md5');
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const https = require('https').Server(options);
const io = require('socket.io')(https);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

нужно ли устанавливать дополнительные библиотеки и какие вы посоветуете.
можно ли обойтись без библиотек?

Comment: На php создаешь API, в котором принимаешь данные от сервера. На Node.js делаешь запрос к API и отправляешь данные. Это самый простой вариант обмена данными.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь очень многое зависит от того, что из себя представляют приложения на Node и PHP.

В общем случае можно:

- Передавать данные в PHP через REST (если приложение имеет API);
- Построить общую шину данных на основе какого-нибудь Rabbit или Kafka.

> можно ли обойтись без библиотек?

Для REST может и получится без библиотек. Для остального вряд ли.